# how to Return multiple array to Response and receive it in separate arrays::json laravel?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel-5

i have multiple tables data to fetch in one controller method and have to return in json for laravel api. then i wish to use those table data use in different loop for data display.

---

```
    public function getmediSearchmed($med){  

         $results_br = DB::table('table A')->where('medicine', 'like', $med.'%')->get()->toArray(); 
         $results_str = DB::table('table B')->where('medid', 'like', $med.'%')->get()->toArray();       


   return json_encode(array('$first'=>$results_br,'$second'=>$results_str));                  

        }
```

---

```
Now how to receive array FIRST and array SECOND separately to display its data in view page
```

Comment: You can ```json_decode``` whatever you are returning from controller and then  you can perform ```array_chunk``` to split your array.

Comment: can i encrypt ajax response in my url bcz it contains json data and decrypt it in laravel view page

Comment: If its possible it will be bit complicated, not very sure about it.

Comment: show your view and js code